# iframe print not working in chrome when url starts with https

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing, https

1. I have a requirement to print a page without using window.open and window.print functions.
2. I achieved the same using the below code. This works if the url is not starting with https(atleast that is what I figured). If the url is starting with https then chrome print out a blank page. Sometimes on multiple clicks to print link, page data is shown. This code works correctly in IE and FireFox.

I have uploaded a sample test page with this code in below url.

http://mediateqindia.com/testPrint.html (works correctly)

https://mediateqindia.com/testPrint.html (blank page on click print link)

Both links are pointing to the same page .

How to fix this to get in working in chrome in https?

Code on page testPrint.html is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bindddddddddd</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="testPrintDiv" >
Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
<br /><br />
Hellooooooooooooo
<br /><br />
World !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!s
<a href="javascript:printTest();">Print</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>



<script>
function printTest(){
var scale=1;
var contents=document.getElementById("testPrintDiv").innerHTML;
if(!scale){ 
    scale=".9";
}
    var printframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    printframe.name = "printframe";
    printframe.style.position = "absolute";
    printframe.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(printframe);
    var frameDoc = printframe.contentWindow ? printframe.contentWindow : printframe.contentDocument.document ? printframe.contentDocument.document : printframe.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><html><head><title></title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/user/data/css/styles-min.css">');
    frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css">@media print { body {transform: scale('+scale+');} @page{margin-left: 0cm;} body {margin-left:0;padding:0;}'
                +'</style></head><body>');
       frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
       frameDoc.document.close();

       setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["printframe"].focus(); 
            window.frames["printframe"].print();       
             setTimeout(function () {
                document.body.removeChild(printframe);
             },5000);
        }, 750);

    //return false;     
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with loading time of css file.

When below line was commented everthing started working fine.

```
frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="/user/data/css/styles-min.css">');
```

On increasing the intervals specified for setTimeout function the above code was working intermittently.Since time required to fetch the css file would vary with server location, I rewrote the code as below which is now 
working as expected.

```
<script>
function printTest(){
var scale=1;
var contents=document.getElementById("testPrintDiv").innerHTML;
if(!scale){ 
    scale=".9";
}
    var printframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    printframe.name = "printframe";
    printframe.style.position = "absolute";
    printframe.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(printframe);
    var frameDoc = printframe.contentWindow ? printframe.contentWindow : printframe.contentDocument.document ? printframe.contentDocument.document : printframe.contentDocument;
    $.when( $.ajax({url:'/user/data/css/styles-min.css',cache:true}) )
            .done(function(response) {
    frameDoc.document.open();
    frameDoc.document.write('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><html><head><title></title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/user/data/css/styles-min.css">');
    frameDoc.document.write('<style type="text/css">@media Print {body {transform:scale('+scale+')}} @page{margin-left: 0cm;} body {margin-left:0;padding:0;}'
                +'</style></head><body>');
       frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
       frameDoc.document.close();

       setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["printframe"].focus(); 
            window.frames["printframe"].print();       
             setTimeout(function () {
                document.body.removeChild(printframe);
             },1500);
        }, 1500);

    });     
}

</script>
```